# How to maintain GameObject position when changing pivot and anchor preset of the RectTransform

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to retain anchorPosition when changing the pivot point and anchor presets via code - the same way as when you update them in the editor, the anchor position is updated to keep the object in the same position.

Currently, updating these via code results in the GameObject position changing and I would need to recalculate.

**Example**
Given default anchor (.5f, .5f) of the red GO like below:

[image]

if we updated like:

```
var rt = (RectTransform) target.transform;
rt.anchorMax = new Vector2 (.5f, 1);
rt.anchorMin = new Vector2 (.5f, 1);
```

We get:

[image]

Comment: May I ask what are you trying to achieve by doing this? I'm asking so I can better understand your question.

Comment: @Ron I need to change the anchor position of items during gameplay so that they position correctly as screen res changes/scales

Comment: And simply defining the anchoring during edit doesn’t cut it for you? That’s the whole point of anchoring, making your UI elements scale/move according to screen res

Comment: @Ron I am pretty clear on the purpose of anchoring. The example above is a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Unlike changes in the editor, changes to anchoring presets programmatically result in the relevant GO being repositioned.

Comment: Yeah I understood that, I meant, why do you need to change anchoring dynamically in the first place?

Comment: @Ron GO needs to change anchoring during gameplay according to conditions. Unless anchoring is updated, the relevant GO will not position correctly if the resolution is updated at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply remember the position before the anchor change and reassign it after:

```
var rt = (RectTransform) target.transform;
var pos = rt.localPosition;        
rt.anchorMin = new Vector2(.5f, 1);
rt.anchorMax = new Vector2(.5f, 1);
rt.localPosition = pos;
```

Maybe there is a way to avoid this but at least you don't have to recalculate anything.

Comment: I am doing this now using an extension method, but wondered if there was a better way - in case I have overlooked something.

Comment: @SamuelG You can look at what Unity does. The UI code is on [github](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Inspector/RectTransformEditor.cs)

Comment: Thanks @Pluto - seems you and I are doing the same, was concerned I was missing method call or parameter I had missed in the docs